# I have problems with dream texture depht 2 doesnt start the texture

Tags: text-object

I cant start texturized 3d with dream texture stabilityai/stable diffusion depht 2[image]

Comment: That appears to be something to do with a third-party addon which is not part of Blender so you should ask the addon developers directly rather than here.

Comment: make sure your object's material is a default new material